# Macbook can't read Macintosh HD

Tags: mac, hard-drive, ssd, file, guid

I use a late 2013 macbook pro 13 inch retina display.

I tried formatting my internal ssd hard drive (macintosh HD) after it started freezing forever whenever I tried to log in. I tried all the workarounds but nothing helped. I couldn't re-install  the os on the internal hard drive because of an incomplete file vault encryption that was stuck at 'paused. ' I therefore decided to erase my internal hard drive but I formatted it as an MBR instead of Guid Partition Map by mistake. Now my macbook can't read my internal ssd drive at all. It doesn't appear in disk utility and I can't install a new os on it as it doesn't appear when I run an installer from an external thumb drive.

I managed to install and run the os Sierra from an external hard drive but after I log in I immediately get the 'Macintosh HD not ejected properly' message.' When I run disk utility again  it only recognises the external hard drive Im using to run the os. Macintosh HD doesn't appear at all.

I don't think it's a hardware issue because the internal macintosh HD was working fine before I tried to format it. By fine I mean I was able to access my files in safe mode and make a time machine backup.

How can I fix my internal ssd macintosh hard drive? Unfortunately we don't have an istore or authorised service providers in my country (Botswana).

Comment: Does recovery mode(holding cmd-r at boot) work?(without any USB)

Comment: Unfortunately no. It takes almost the whole day downloading the os then gives an error message saying I must seek help from apple website

Comment: You can enter recovery mode though, but you can't reinstall the OS from there, right?

Comment: That is correct. The globe just spins for hours on end then gives me an error directing me to apple website.

Comment: Can you please put an image?

Comment: Do you have another machine available? If so, with the appropriate cable, you could put the "sick" MBP into "Target Disk Mode", then do the reformatting from the "healthy" Mac. TDM can work through Thunderbolt or Firewire with appriate cables.